# Possible to Start Playing a Local Video at a certain minute or second time mark? (Like on Youtube)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In iOS, I am fully familiar with how to play a local video once a button is pressed. My question: is it possible to have that button play a particular time or minute/second mark in a video?

For example, on Youtube, you can link to a particular part of a video by adding "&t=31m08s" at the end of the URL. Is there any way to do this in iOS?

Comment: Please read the description of the `xcode` tag. It does not apply to your question. What you want to do is about iOS and the Cocoa-touch framework, not Xcode.

Comment: rmaddy, thanks for the tip, and please accept my apologies for this mistake.

Comment: No apology needed. I was simply pointing it for you so you know for future reference. Sorry I can't help with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MPMoviePlayerController you need to adopt the MPMediaPlayback Protocol which includes the method currentPlaybackTime. From the reference: "Changing the value of this property moves the playhead to the new location."

Here is the Reference for [MPMediaPlayback Protocol.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/MPMediaPlayback/currentPlaybackTime)